# Populating ANY elements on a web service in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services

Can someone point me to a C# example where they populate a request and receive the response for a web service where the schema is mostly implemented as ANY elements?

I have added a web service reference to my project.  The WSDL/schema for the web service has most of the body of the service request and response as an 'ANY' element.  I know the underlying schema based on implementing a client to this web service request in Java.  Thanks in advance for help.

```
ServiceGenericRequest_Type requestBody = <init>
GenericRequestData_Type genericRequest = <init>;

// here is where the ANY element starts
genericRequest.Any = new System.Xml.XmlElement[1];

// receive error that I can not create abstract type
System.Xml.XmlNode inqNode = new System.Xml.XmlNode();

genericRequest.Any[0].AppendChild(inqNode);`
```

Comment: Your question may be too broad for stackoverflow.  What have you tried so far?  Can you share some initial code?  Do you have auto-generated classes you want to populate, that consist mainly of `public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any` arrays?  If so, maybe see [`How to initialize XmlElement[]?`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32900890/3744182).

Comment: Added code snippet in my original post

Comment: Did you generate this with svcutil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is fairly general so I'm going to narrow it down a bit to the following situation: you have a type with an [`[XmlAnyElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) member like so:

```
public class GenericRequestData_Type
{
    private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And you would like to initialize the `Any` field to the following XML:

```
<Contacts>
  <Contact>
    <Name>Patrick Hines</Name>
    <Phone>206-555-0144</Phone>
    <Address>
      <Street1>123 Main St</Street1>
      <City>Mercer Island</City>
      <State>WA</State>
      <Postal>68042</Postal>
    </Address>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

How can this be done?

There are several options, so I'll break it down into a few different answers.

Firstly, you could design c# classes corresponding to your desired XML using a code-generation tool such as http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ or Visual Studio's [Paste XML as Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx).  Then you can serialize those classes directly to an `XmlNode` hierarchy using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) combined with [`XmlDocument.CreateNavigator().AppendChild()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163341.aspx).

First, introduce the following extension methods:

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static XmlDocument AsXmlDocument<T>(this T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
            new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(writer, o, ns ?? NoStandardXmlNamespaces());
        return doc;
    }

    public static XmlElement AsXmlElement<T>(this T o, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        return o.AsXmlDocument(ns, serializer).DocumentElement;
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(this XmlElement element, XmlSerializer serializer = null)
    {
        using (var reader = new ProperXmlNodeReader(element))
            return (T)(serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(typeof(T))).Deserialize(reader);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return an XmlSerializerNamespaces that disables the default xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static XmlSerializerNamespaces NoStandardXmlNamespaces()
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        return ns;
    }
}

public class ProperXmlNodeReader : XmlNodeReader
{
    // Bug fix from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30115691/3744182
    // To http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102275/deserialize-object-property-with-stringreader-vs-xmlnodereader
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/8799/nathan-baulch
    public ProperXmlNodeReader(XmlNode node) : base(node) { }

    public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix)
    {
        return NameTable.Add(base.LookupNamespace(prefix));
    }
}
```

Next, define types corresponding to your `<Contacts>` hierarchy:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Address")]
public class Address
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Street1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Postal")]
    public string Postal { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Contacts")]
public class Contacts
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Contact")]
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("GenericRequestData_Type")]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Emails")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Email")]
    public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Issues")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Id")]
    public List<long> IssueIds { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, initialize your `GenericRequestData_Type` as follows:

```
var genericRequest = new GenericRequestData_Type();

var contacts = new Contacts
{
    Contact = new Contact
    {
        Name = "Patrick Hines",
        Phone = "206-555-0144",
        Address = new Address
        {
            Street1 = "123 Main St",
            City = "Mercer Island",
            State = "WA",
            Postal = "68042",
        },
    }
};
genericRequest.Any = new[] { contacts.AsXmlElement() };
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fxiyfy).

Answer (score 0):

[`XmlNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) is an abstract base type.  You can create concrete [`XmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) objects and add then to your `Any` array following the instructions in [Create New Nodes in the DOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k44daxya.aspx):

- First, create an [`XmlDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).  While the document does not appear explicitly in the `XmlElement [] Any` array, it is needed to subsequently create elements.
- Create elements using [`XmlDocument.CreateElement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement.aspx)
- Add the created elements to their parents as appropriate using [`XmlNode.AppendChild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild.aspx)
- Set text values by using [`XmlElement.InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx).

Thus the following will work:

```
var dom = new XmlDocument();
var contacts = dom.CreateElement("Contacts");
dom.AppendChild(contacts);
var contact = dom.CreateElement("Contact");
contacts.AppendChild(contact);
var name = dom.CreateElement("Name");
contact.AppendChild(name);
name.InnerText = "Patrick Hines";
var phone = dom.CreateElement("Phone");
contact.AppendChild(phone);
phone.InnerText = "206-555-0144";
var address = dom.CreateElement("Address");
contact.AppendChild(address);
var street1 = dom.CreateElement("Street1");
address.AppendChild(street1);
street1.InnerText = "123 Main St";
var city = dom.CreateElement("City");
address.AppendChild(city);
city.InnerText = "Mercer Island";
var state = dom.CreateElement("State");
address.AppendChild(state);
state.InnerText = "WA";
var postal = dom.CreateElement("Postal");
address.AppendChild(postal);
postal.InnerText = "68042";

var genericRequest = new GenericRequestData_Type();
genericRequest.Any = new[] { dom.DocumentElement };
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LuvLCq).

Comment: `First, create an XmlDocument... ` Proxy code generated from a WSDL doesn't have an XML document until its hitting the wire.

Comment: @StingyJack - it doesn't have to be the same `XmlDocument` used during serialization when hitting the wire.  It can be a temp `XmlDocument` made up on the fly.  It needs to be constructed to manufacture the `XmlElement` objects inside the `XmlElement[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

[`XmlNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) is a type in the old [XML Document Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87.aspx) that dates from c# 1.1.  It has been superseded by the much easier to use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) object model.  What is not well known is that [`[XmlAnyElementAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) actually supports this API.  Thus in your `GenericRequestData_Type` type you could manually change the `Any` property to be of type `System.Xml.Linq.XElement[]`:

```
public class GenericRequestData_Type
{
    private System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] anyField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.Linq.XElement[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize the array easily as follows, following the instructions in [Creating XML Trees in C# (LINQ to XML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693096.aspx):

```
// Taken from 
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693096.aspx
var contacts =
    new XElement("Contacts",
        new XElement("Contact",
            new XElement("Name", "Patrick Hines"),
            new XElement("Phone", "206-555-0144"),
            new XElement("Address",
                new XElement("Street1", "123 Main St"),
                new XElement("City", "Mercer Island"),
                new XElement("State", "WA"),
                new XElement("Postal", "68042")
            )
        )
    );

var genericRequest = new GenericRequestData_Type();
genericRequest.Any = new[] { contacts };
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FACQdI).