# C# How to set value on object

Tags: c#, asmx

This my web service request:

```cs
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Duration", typeof(string), DataType="duration", Order=1)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EndDate", typeof(System.DateTime), Order=1)]
public object Item {
    get { return this.itemField; }
    set { this.itemField = value; }
}
```

How to set the value EndDate and Duration from the object.

Just now i just set like below:

```cs
dateRange.Item = DateTime.now
```

From above code onli set the EndDate and how to set the value from duration.

Comment: Why did you use `{ }` - what was the intent there? Are you trying to make it `null`, perhaps?

Comment: You need to create an xml node and assign its attributes. Honestly, you better try using the xml serialization instead of doing that. You have some resources here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/215659/5950070

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `{ }` for an empty object is valid in javascript, but not in C#.

For C# try one of the following:

```
dateRange.Item = new object(); // object without properties
// or
dateRange.Item = new { id = 1, text = "Hello" }; // object with 2 properties
// or
dateRange.Item = DateTime.Now; // a DateTime struct
// or
dateRange.Item = null; // *not* an object
```

Comment: Thanks you for the response already working now